# How to set Search Depth in Windows File Explorer

Tags: windows, search, explorer

I want to find only folders which are named 'target' and are in a subfolder for example:
matches with:

- c:\projects\test1\node_modules
- c:\projects\test13\node_modules

matches I do **NOT**:

- c:\projects\test1\node_modules\blabla\node_modules
- c:\projects\test1\node_modules\blabla\node_modules\lalla\node_modules

Windows 10 Pro\21H2

even a that's currently not possible is a good answer ;)

Comment: Try typing "target kind: folder" into the search window (without the quotes)

Comment: tried but then the following match is also in my results which i don't want:
c:\projects\test1\node_modules\blabla\node_modules